# Unable Pass Value to Matdialog

Tags: angular, angular5

I am not able to Pass data to Matdialog. I am using [this link](https://stackblitz.com/angular/kooevkkoable?file=app%2Fdialog-overview-example.html) and i copy paste the code including file name also.But it works in the link but not in my code.I put the log inside the opendialog function it show name undefined.

Comment: Your example works as expected. data.name is filled

Comment: i am not getting any value for the data object

Comment: the issue is resolved by adding form control

Comment: What issue? Your stackblitz was fine

Comment: i add formControlName="name".